# How to set the config file location for webdriver IO

Tags: webdriver-io

I have set up a Webdriver IO test framework and manually created my config file. This is located in a config folder, however when I run wdio I get an error message stating that there is missing configuration.

How do I tell wdio the config file (wdio.conf.js) location or do I have to have it placed at root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the location of the config file as the first parameter to your `wdio` command. For example:

```
npx wdio ./config/wdio.conf.js
```